# How can I remove a dynamically added dropdown based on a selection from an earlier dropdown

Tags: jquery, html, event-handling, dynamically-generated

I'm trying to do something simple and its becoming complex:
User selects a specific option from dropdown 1 -> new dropdown (dropdown 2) menu from AJAX is appended -
User changes mind and chooses a different option from dropdown 1 -> Dropdown 2 vanishes.

I'm using the selection in a  box as a means to generate a second  by way of an AJAX call. This all works fine, and i'm using a JQuery on change event handler to listen for the choice and run the AJAX. However, since the on change handler is attached to the dropdown that generates the second list by the  i.e higher up in the DOM - everytime the second list also changes it resets itself (as the AJAX call fires again) - and doesnt allow the user to choose something in it.

I can make it work by removing the on change event listener in the AJAX call but then this means that if someone changes their mind and changes the first dropdown then the second one will not be hidden. This should be easy and I feel like it's becoming overly complicated - does anyone have any pointers?

```
$(document).on('change', "table#subjectselection", myFunction);
var counter = 1;  //this is the counter to ensure unique IDs for dynamically added elements
var appended = false;
var options = [];
function ajaxCheck(subject){
$.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  url: 'tutorprofileinput.php',
  data: {"subject": subject},
  dataType:'json',

success:function(data){
//this creates the new dropdown to be inserted
var objData = data[0];
var id = objData.id;
 options +='<div class="select">'
 options +='<select class="language" name="language[]">'; 
 options +='<option>Select Language</option>'; 
 $.each(data, function (key, val) {
    options += '<option value="' + val.topic + '">' + val.topic + '</option>';
       });     
           $('#more'+counter+'').show();  
        $('#more'+counter+'').html(options);
        $(document).off('change', "table#subjectselection", myFunction); 
        }); 
          },
  error:function(){
    // failed request; give feedback to user
    $('#ajax-panel').html('<p class="error"><strong>Oops!</strong> Try that again in a few moments.</p>');
  }
 });
}

function myFunction(){
//this function listens for the choice and passes it to the AJAX
    var subject = $("select#topic"+counter+">option:selected").text(); 
//and changes the visibility based on the value of the selection
    if (subject=="Languages"){
    ajaxCheck(subject);}
    else if (subject != "Languages"){
    $('#more'+counter+'').hide();
        }
}

function Repeat(){
//this function adds another row with a new set of dropdowns which are to behave as the originals do
counter++;
$(document).on('change', "table#subjectselection", myFunction);

var selecoptions = '<tr><td><div class="subjselect"><div class="select"><select id="level'+counter+'" name="level[]" form="tutor_profile_input"><option value="">Level Taught</option><option value="primary">Primary</option><option value="junior_high">Junior High</option><option value="senior_high">Senior High</option><option value="gcse">GCSE</option><option value="alevel">A Level</option><option value="sat">SAT</option><option value="GMAT">GMAT</option><option value="university">University</option><option value="all">All Levels</option></select></div></td><td><div class="select"><select id="topic'+counter+'" name="topic[]" form="tutor_profile_input"><option value="">Math</option><option value="">Biology</option><option value="">Chemistry</option><option value="">Physics</option><option value="">Languages</option><option value="">English Literature</option><option value="">Politics</option><option value="">Art</option><option value="">Latin</option><option value="">Psychology</option><option value="">Medicine</option><option value="">Anthropology</option></select></td><td id="more'+counter+'"></td></tr>';

$('table#subjectselection').append(selecoptions);

}}
```

and the HTML:

```
<div id="subjectselectiondiv" style="width:inherit;">
<h4>Select up to three subjects that you are able to tutor</h4>
<table id="subjectselection" >
<tr>

            <td>
                <div class='select'>
                    <select id="topic1" class="topic" name="topic[]" form="tutor_profile_input">
                    <option value="">Math</option>
                    <option value="">Biology</option>
                    <option value="">Chemistry</option>
                    <option value="">Physics</option>
                    <option value="">Languages</option>
                    <option value="">English Literature</option>
                    <option value="">Politics</option>
                    <option value="">Art</option>
                    <option value="">Latin</option>
                    <option value="">Psychology</option>
                    <option value="">Medicine</option>
                    <option value="">Anthropology</option>
                    </select></td>
                    <td id="more1"></td>
            <td><a href="#" id="another" class="more" onclick="Repeat()">Add Another Subject</a>
</td>
            </tr>           
            </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Instead of `$(document).on('change', "table#subjectselection", myFunction);` can you not narrow it to `$("select.topic").change(myFunction);`? Why does the event have to be at the table level?

Comment: thanks mccannff - that works in terms of showing the content in the dropdown without re-firing the AJAX call - which is great - but it still doesnt remove the second div if you've added a new subject i.e. after the Repeat() function has fired - if the user goes back and changes from Languages to something else in an earlier dropdown the (earlier) dynamically added dropdown remains as a relic

Answer (score 1):

It seems like this is happening because you have bind the `change` event with the **`subjectselection`** table. It is fine that ajax is called when you change the value of **`#topic1`** selectbox. But, as your **`subjectselection`** table is binded with the `change` event, the ajax gets fired when you change any element's value which is inside the **`subjectselection`** table. That's why when you change the newly added **selectbox's** value, a change on whole of the table is detected which results your problem.

Try binding specific elements **(which in this case are your selectboxes)**  instead of whole div or table.

Hope it helps on your issue!

Comment: that works in terms of showing the content in the dropdown without re-firing the AJAX call - which is great - but it still doesnt remove the second div if you've added a new subject i.e. after the Repeat() function has fired - if the user goes back and changes from Languages to something else in an earlier dropdown the (earlier) dynamically added dropdown remains as a relic –